# Wideimage Apply Mask

Tags: php, image, mask

Anyone having a problem using applyMask method in [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/) library for PHP?

This is the code I have and it seems it should be pretty straightforward but it's not working.

```
$image = WideImage::load($tempfile);
$mask = dirname(__FILE__)."/../images/okvircki.png";
$mask_wi = WideImage::load($mask);

$image->applyMask($mask_wi,0,0);
$image->saveToFile('image_egg.png');
```

$tempfile is a JPG and $mask a greyscale PNG. The end result is the same as tempfile img.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't seem to format the code part correctly...

Comment: I've formated it for you, you have to select all the code you wish to format and then click {} button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"applayMask()" (as any other WideImage method) returns the modiffied resource and does not modify the resource it was called on.

This means you have to do something like this:

```
$image = $image->applyMask($mask_wi,0,0);
```